# gradle, what does this mean? "debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')"

Tags: android, gradle

Here is my gradle setting:

```
    sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
buildTypes{
    release{
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug{
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

I coundn't find the `build-types/debug` folder and `build-types/release` folder although I set these `debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')  release.setRoot('build-types/release')`

what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setRoot` method is used to set the path for a specific build-type's configuration. So you have specific configuration for `debug` and `release`, you will need to create those folders and put the build-type specific files in there. With your current configuration, you are saying that all the common files are in the `main` build type, and any build-type specific files will be in the folders that you are specifying.

That being said, you are better off using the recommended project structure that the android plugin supports. See the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure) for this. It will keep your `build.gradle` file clean if you follow the conventions.

Comment: So it means that "If I create `build-types/debug` folder and put something like `test.java` in it, when I build the debug version, it will be merged into the main files?"  I don't quite understand what the `main build type` mean, there are only debug and release types, aren't they?

Comment: `main` contains the base of your project - the shared code for any release/flavor type. The Android gradle plugin by default has two build-types - `debug` and `release`. They will both use `main` as the base, but anything that you put in the `debug` or `release` folders will be merged with `main` to generate the actual build.

I would suggest reading the official docs on this: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

There are several tutorials online about configuring Gradle build types/flavors.